# Google Analytics: web profiles missing and data lost

Tags: google-analytics

Logged in a Google Analytics account that had been created/setup with a tracking code for two Websites several years ago.  Have not logged in for a while (at least 6-8 months), but at that time, everything was working as expected.

Logged in today and noticed that there were no Website profiles.  Tried adding an "existing domain" profile for one of the missing sites and after an hour or so, the tracking was "successful" (green checkbox) but still no historic data.

No changes to the account have been done as far as I know.  Any idea what would have caused this to be lost and how the historical data be recovered?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the profiles could have disappeared without someone deleting them but creating new ones won't bring back the historical data. I don't think there's any way to get the data back if the profiles have gone.

At this point you could check to see if you have any log files for the websites as they are probably the only history you have. If they were switched on (not always the case) and not deleted (they often get rotated and zipped up) then they could be some use. You can't use log files with Google Analytics but you can try out a log file analyzer such as AWStats to see if what you need is available.